# Ozone sensor with range above 5ppm?

Tags: ozone, sensor

I am attempting to find or build a sensor for controlling an ozone generator. To do this, the sensor will need to see the range of at least 0 to 5% (50000ppm). The [commercially available sensors](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/spec-sensors-llc/110-406/7689223) I have found so far are all in the 0 to 5ppm range; primarily used for air quality and safety. It seems like a sensor in this range should exist, but perhaps I am using the wrong vocabulary for searching.

This [website](https://www.aeroqual.com/blog/electrochemical-sensors-hmos) mentions electrochemical ozone sensors as well but looks like they only go up to 20ppm.

Ozone obviously [absorbs UV](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Absorption-wavelength-of-ozone-135-Advantages-of-optical-absorption-spectroscopy-are_fig1_288835123), but I have not been able to identify this being used outside of a lab environment for sensing concentration. Here is an [expensive lab ozone sensor](https://www.ecosensors.com/product/uv-100-uv-ozone-analyzer-data-sheet/) that goes up to 999ppm. Might be able to build a sensor based on this principle, but maybe I am overlooking some other common atmosphere gas that would give false readings (water vapor, VOCs, etc).

Are these the only three technologies used for measuring ozone? Other creative methods?

Comment: There is something called linear dynamic range of sensors. You are aiming for a really *insensitive" sensor which responds to 0 to 5%. With 5% ozone, it will start damaging everything.

Comment: How fancy do you want to be? Ozone absorbs infrared radiation too. Look at the infrared spectrum of ozone.

Comment: @AChem, Good idea on the infrared absorption; I will have a look!